# How to convert an image from HSV to RGB using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to convert an image in the HSV color space to RGB but all the the solutions do a single pixel (tuple) conversion. For example,

```
import colorsys
colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.4)
```

Is there a vectorized way of converting an entire HSV image to RGB at once?

Comment: What program/function created the HSV image? I mean, where did you get it from?

Comment: I have dense optical flow gradients which I'm converting to an HSV image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PIL image you can use [convert](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) method. eg.

```
image = Image.new("HSV",(10, 10))
rgb_image = image.convert(mode="RGB")
```